# Twine can not upload to pypi.org

Tags: python, pypi, twine

I have a python package (xyz) that was on python.pypi.org. I am trying to release a new version and I am using twine for upload. I fixed everything in the ~/.pypirc file as explained on tutorials. When I run the following command:

```
twine upload dist/*
```

I got the following output:

> Uploading distributions to https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
>
> Uploading xyz-1.9.1.tar.gz
>
> HTTPError: 400 Client Error: provides: Invalid requirement: 'xyz (1.9.1)' 
>   for url: https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/

I was not sure why this is happening but I am guessing it could be my setup.py file but here are the block in my setup() part.

```
setup(
name='xyz',
version=__version__,
author='xyz',
author_email='xyz',
description='xyz package for xyz',
long_description=long_description,
url='xyz',
packages=PACKAGES,
package_dir=PACKAGE_DIR,
package_data=PACKAGE_DATA,
ext_modules=EXTENSIONS,
license='MIT License',
keywords=('xyz'),
classifiers=[
             'Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable',
             'Intended Audience :: Education',
             'Intended Audience :: Science/Research',
             'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
             'Operating System :: MacOS',
             'Operating System :: Microsoft :: Windows',
             'Operating System :: POSIX',
             'Programming Language :: Python',
             'Programming Language :: Python :: 2',
             'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
             'Topic :: Scientific/Engineering :: xyz',
             'Topic :: Scientific/Engineering :: xyz',
            ],
scripts=SCRIPTS,
requires=['NumPy (>=1.7)', ],
provides=['xyz'.format(__version__)]
```

)

Could anyone help me on this? Thanks.

Note: "xyz" is the replacement name for the package. There will be no duplicate packages.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm assuming that the `provides=['xyz'.format(__version__)]` line in your `setup.py` is actually `provides=['xyz ({})'.format(__version__)]`, as otherwise this doesn't make any sense.)

First of all, the `provides` and `requires` arguments to `setup()` are deprecated and, as far as I am aware, were never actually used for anything.  `requires` should now be spelled `install_requires` instead.  There is no replacement for `provides`, as trying to give that field any formal meaning leads to problems that outweigh the minuscule benefit that such a field might bring.  However, if you insist on using `provides`, it appears that PyPI for some reason requires the field's values to be valid requirement strings, which `"xyz (1.9.1)"` is not; a valid requirement would look like "`xyz == 1.9.1`" or `"xyz (== 1.9.1)"` instead, but, as indicated previously, none of those actually mean anything.

PS: I would suggest you read ["Packaging and Distributing Projects"](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/) from the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/) for modern, recommended Python packaging practices.